# System boots to initrmafs prompt after rdiff-backup restore

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup, initramfs

I was making daily backups with rdiff-backup. system and data partitions separately.

Now I restored the system from the backup, but it doens't boot.
All I get is an (initramfs) prompt.

I typed `echo $REASON` and it says there was no init file found.

What's going on? Is my backup corrupted?

I excluded some system directories in the backup to avoid writing /dev/ /sys/ /run/ and /proc/ as well as /media/ and /data (where another partition is being mounted). This is the backup script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /media/backup
mount /dev/sda4 /media/backup

time nice rdiff-backup -v9 --force --check-destination-dir /media/backup/root/
time nice rdiff-backup -v9 --force --check-destination-dir /media/backup/data/

mkdir /media/backup/root
time nice rdiff-backup -v9 --exclude /home/citron/.cache/ --exclude /media/ --exclude /mnt/ --exclude /dev/ --exclude /proc/ --exclude /sys/ --exclude /run/ --exclude /data/ / /media/backup/root/

mkdir /media/backup/data
time nice rdiff-backup -v9 --exclude /data/lost+found/ /data/ /media/backup/data/

umount /media/backup
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the system directories are present on the restored system partition:

```
/dev/
/run/
/sys/
/proc/
```

The backup script looks like it could have omitted not only the contents of these directories, but the directories as well - in that case the system won't be able to boot properly, becasue there is no directory to mount the kernel interfaces into.

I guess you've used a LiveCD to restore from the backup. Go back to the LiveCD, mount the restored system partition, navigate to the root dir there and do

```
sudo mkdir dev run sys proc
```

This will make sure all the directories are in place. Reboot and see if it helps.